# (Office add-in) manifest icon does not have the right resolution according to office store team, but it does according to the documentation

Tags: office365

I got my Office add-in rejected from the Office store with the comment that the High Resolution icon in the manifest should refer to an image that's 64x64px. The weird thing is, it says 128x128px in the documentation at https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/highresolutioniconurl. Anyone else had a similar experience with the Office store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The high resolution image should be 128x128 for Outlook add-ins and 64x64 for Word/Excel/PowerPoint add-ins if my memory serves me correctly.

You're right in that it's odd that it doesn't say this in the documentation but it certainly has been like that before. There is a slight chance that the criteria have actually changed very recently and the store team has not been made aware yet.